# accessing the variable of an extension method (C#)

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Is it possible to modify the this/focus variable in a static extension method?

For example:

```
public static class AnimExtensions
{
    public static int anim(this float f, float to, float time)
    {
        return Animation.Start(a => f = a, f, to, time);
    }
}
```

I would like to call the Animation.Start method using an extension to float, by using the lambda function on the 'this' variable.  The this keyword is not allowed in extension methods, but is there another way to access/use the variable in this fashion?

Comment: To what end though? No one else can even access `f`.

Comment: If you need the calling context, make that the extension parameter.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - the idea is that the variable that is being acted upon would be modified, allowing me to make calls like: someFloat.anim(endVal, time);  Instead of having to write Animation.Start(a=>someFloat=a, someFloat, endVal, time);

Comment: @asawyer - I know I could just make an extra parameter, but I was making this extension to cut down on unnecessary typing

Comment: @asawyer, actually I can't use a parameter, as it would need to be ref or out, and you can't use ref or out in lambda methods.  I would have to use an Action parameter which means typing the lambda all the time (which is my main aim really, to cut down on writing lambdas all over my code).

Comment: @user1189721 It **is** possible to use `ref` with a lambda function, as in `(ref float a) => a = SOMETHING;`. But it's not possible to have an extension method that assigns "this" to some other object (and that would also feel very unnatural in my opinion).

Comment: @Jeppe - whenever I try (ref float a) => a = SOMETHING I get the compiler error "Parameter 1 should not be declared with the 'ref' keyword
"

Comment: But you can't use the framework's `Action<float>` delegate, like I said somewhere else. Define your own type: `public delegate void MyActionWithRef(ref float a);` in the same namespace. A method signature *with* `ref` is considered different than one without. But I'm not sure if this will help you with your problem (but you *will* learn something new about delegates).

Answer (score 8):

You can certainly modify the parameter - but it won't have any effect, as the argument is passed by value as per normal methods.

You can't declare the first parameter of an extension method to be `ref` or `out`, which is what would be required for it to have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking. What's the type of the first argument of the `Animation.Start` method?

The type `float` (`System.Single`) is **immutable** so you can't modify the `f` object. You can assign `f` to a new object (saying e.g. `f = 3.14F;` or `f++;`) but as Jon Skeet explains in his answer, that's useless (`ref`/`out` can't combine with `this`).

If you make an extension method on a **mutable** reference type, say `List<>`, then it's possible to modify the "this" object, as in:

```
public static void AbsAll(this List<float> list)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
    list[i] = Math.Abs(list[i]);
}
```

It still won't be useful to assign `list` to a new object, of course.

Comment: The first type of the Start method is Action<float>, which I think is where everything falls down for me.  I want to animate floats, but do so without lengthy function calls all the time, but it looks like I'm stuck with the more verbose method.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but the type `Action<T>` does not have the `ref` modifyer on its sole argument. It says `T obj`, it does not say `ref T obj`. See [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx). You can make your own `RefAction` delegate type, but I'm not sure that's what you want.